# Get a standard deviation by group and subtract from mean column standard deviation in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a toy *df* that is included below. For columns *Grades* and *Age*, I need to find the difference between mean standard deviation from the total standard deviation, by *University*. The values in the new table - which should have 4 rows and 2 columns - should therefore represent the differences in the standard deviation of *Grades* and *Age* in each *University* compared to the total df standard deviation of *Grades* and *Ages* (across all universities).

Data:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble::tribble(
           ~University, ~Countries, ~Grades, ~Age,
        "University-1",      "USA",      46,    29,
        "University-1",       "UK",      84,    30,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",       5,    28,
        "University-1",    "Spain",      40,    26,
        "University-1", "Portugal",      49,    29,
        "University-1",    "Italy",      16,    24,
        "University-1",      "USA",      34,    19,
        "University-1",       "UK",      66,    28,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",       9,    25,
        "University-1",    "Spain",      80,    20,
        "University-1", "Portugal",      55,    20,
        "University-1",    "Italy",       4,    21,
        "University-1",      "USA",      93,    18,
        "University-1",       "UK",      62,    28,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",      80,    30,
        "University-2",    "Spain",       1,    22,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      56,    25,
        "University-2",    "Italy",       9,    29,
        "University-2",      "USA",      40,    21,
        "University-2",       "UK",      54,    20,
        "University-2",   "Sweden",      60,    24,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      77,    21,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      22,    18,
        "University-2",    "Italy",      53,    29,
        "University-2",      "USA",      11,    21,
        "University-2",       "UK",      65,    27,
        "University-2",   "Sweden",      24,    27,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      18,    23,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      73,    19,
        "University-2",    "Italy",      79,    22,
        "University-1",      "USA",       2,    26,
        "University-1",       "UK",      83,    23,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",       5,    19,
        "University-1",    "Spain",      75,    19,
        "University-1", "Portugal",      12,    21,
        "University-1",    "Italy",      68,    29,
        "University-1",      "USA",     100,    21,
        "University-1",       "UK",      49,    21,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",      81,    20,
        "University-1",    "Spain",      99,    23,
        "University-1", "Portugal",      82,    24,
        "University-1",    "Italy",      23,    26,
        "University-1",      "USA",      86,    30,
        "University-1",       "UK",      50,    20,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",       4,    19,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      12,    25,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      12,    21,
        "University-2",    "Italy",      45,    21,
        "University-2",      "USA",      16,    26,
        "University-2",       "UK",      56,    23,
        "University-2",   "Sweden",      63,    24,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      37,    28,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      86,    21,
        "University-2",    "Italy",      95,    18,
        "University-2",      "USA",      56,    20,
        "University-2",       "UK",      27,    20,
        "University-2",   "Sweden",       3,    27,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      18,    27,
        "University-3", "Portugal",      68,    27,
        "University-3",    "Italy",      48,    21,
        "University-3", "Portugal",      86,    21,
        "University-3",    "Italy",      95,    18,
        "University-3",      "USA",      56,    20,
        "University-3",       "UK",      27,    20,
        "University-3",   "Sweden",       3,    27,
        "University-3",    "Spain",      18,    27,
        "University-3", "Portugal",      68,    27,
        "University-3",    "Italy",      48,    21,
        "University-4", "Portugal",      86,    21,
        "University-4",    "Italy",      95,    18,
        "University-4",      "USA",      56,    20,
        "University-4",       "UK",      27,    20,
        "University-4",   "Sweden",       3,    27,
        "University-4",    "Spain",      18,    27,
        "University-4", "Portugal",      68,    27,
        "University-4",    "Italy",      48,    21
        )
```

My attempt at getting at this:

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(grades_sd = sd(Grades),
           age_sd = sd(Age)) %>% 
    group_by(University) %>%
    summarise(Grades_sd = sd(Grades) - grades_sd,
              Age_sd = sd(Age) - age_sd)
```

This code performs the correct (I think) calculations but outputs the table in the wrong format. I'd appreciate any guidance on this.

Edit: Including expected output below.

```
output <- tibble::tribble(
           ~University, ~Grades_sd, ~Age_sd,
        "University-1", 2.666482, 0.40233934,   
        "University-2", -2.790652, -0.34945170, 
        "University-3", 0.881169, -0.03754330,
        "University-4", 2.398070, 0.06701784)
```

Comment: Included expected output in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the ungrouped version of the `df`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(University) %>%
    summarise(Grades_sd = sd(Grades) - sd(df$Grades),
              Age_sd    = sd(Age) - sd(df$Age))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   University   Grades_sd  Age_sd
#>   <chr>            <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 University-1     2.67   0.402 
#> 2 University-2    -2.79  -0.349 
#> 3 University-3    -0.881 -0.0375
#> 4 University-4     2.40   0.0670
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This is a neat solution.

Answer (score 3):

since there is the same record for each group, `summarise` repeats them. taking unique value will return only one and there will be one summary row for each group.

```
df %>% 
    mutate(grades_sd = sd(Grades),
           age_sd = sd(Age)) %>% 
    group_by(University) %>%
    summarise(Grades_sd = sd(Grades) - unique(grades_sd),
              Age_sd = sd(Age) - unique(age_sd))
```

output;

```
  University   Grades_sd  Age_sd
  <chr>            <dbl>   <dbl>
1 University-1     2.67   0.402 
2 University-2    -2.79  -0.349 
3 University-3    -0.881 -0.0375
4 University-4     2.40   0.0670
```